# Form select option not selected after refresh

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am having issues in Chrome `Version 52.0.2730.0 canary (64-bit)` when it comes to using `selected` on an option element inside of a `select` element. It is fine on the first visit, but when there is a refresh, it is no longer the option and the select is empty. Looked at other questions and answers and could not find one that was able to handle this issue. Any help would be appreciated:

```
<select name="testSelect">
    <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
    <option value="1">Not selected</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's to be expected if you use Canary. It's a developer's version, if you want behavior that's normally expected, then use the stable version.

Comment: Ajax, php, javascript with a cookie or session variable... To name a few